# UML diagrams exercises

Tags: uml

I have learned a lot of fancy diagrams to be used in modeling software , But only Use case and Class diagrams seems to have a clear usage for me . I searched the web a lot and I found little exercise . I need a book or a document which contains loads of UML examples so I can start thinking and trying the tools I have learned .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Oriented-Analysis-Applications-Addison-Wesley-Technology/dp/020189551X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1289046740&sr=1-1) by [Grady Booch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch) is a must-read on UML and its application.
Theoretically sound, and illustrated with some great examples (the application part of the title).

Comment: BTW - Booch is one of the original developers of UML.

Comment: I found it to be the most useful in my case among the other books .

Answer (score 1):

I've found [UML 2 and the Unified Process: Practical Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321278)  to be pretty useful. Search Amazon and read reviews!

When it comes to real-world applicability, my experience is that the two diagram types you mention are THE most used ones. The days of RUP are over, everything is going Agile now, so excessive diagramming is frowned upon by customers who want to see their money converted to software, not paper.

Comment: _excessive_ modeling might be frowned upon, but using concise uml diagrams to express your thoughts and communicate with your team sounds pretty "agile" to me

Comment: The general feeling I get is that light-weight methods are preferred by customers. That doesn't mean that UML is the stuff of the past, just that the two diagrams the OP mentioned (+ some sequence diagrams) usually are quite enough to communicate the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found "Object-oriented systems analysis and design using UML" by Simon Bennett, Steve McRobb and Ray Farmer quite good (if I recall correctly there's a few case studies at the end of each chapter), and "Software Engineering" by Ian Sommerville covers UML and its use in requirements engineering, design, etc. too.

The following website provides a brief overview of the main diagram types too, unfortunately the self-test links don't seem to work anymore though. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863

EDIT: Same link on WBM: https://web.archive.org/web/20180206093853/https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863

Answer (score 0):

Some may argue that the reason you can't find much use for UML diagrams other than Use-case and Class diagrams is that these other diagrams aren't that useful!  Not sure I'd agree with this myself, but on the other hand I'd say that Class/Use-case diagrams are more widely used and more generally useful / applicable than their more exotic cousins.

Answer (score 0):

"[Applying UML and Patterns. An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development](http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/index.php?title=Book_Applying_UML_and_Patterns)" ([online copy](http://books.google.com/books?id=r8i-4En_aa4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Applying+UML+and+Patterns.+An+Introduction+to+Object-Oriented+Analysis+and+Design+and+Iterative+Development%22&hl=ru&ei=myDXTOufNMGYOrHS_MQJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Applying%20UML%20and%20Patterns.%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Object-Oriented%20Analysis%20and%20Design%20and%20Iterative%20Development%22&f=false)) by Craig Larman ISBN 0-13-148906-2. There are many UML diagrams explained with practical examples.